# Visual C# Creating a database path so that it runs on different PCs

Tags: c#, database, path, local

I have created a Visual C# application on Visual Studio 2010 that has a database. The path is `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Sch\AAAA\Project\Scholarships\Scholarships\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

But every time I want to run the application on a different PC, I have to change the path from `E:\Sch\AAAA\Project\Scholarships\Scholarships\Database1.mdf` to `C:\Folder1\Scholarships\Scholarships\Database1.mdf` or something

Is there any way to change the path to a local path or something so that I won't have to change it every time I run the application on a different PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the DataDirectory substitution string

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyAppDataFolder\Database1.mdf;" +
"Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

[Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-)

> |DataDirectory| (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string
> that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to
> hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full
> path to the database could be serialized in different places.
> DataDirectory also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy
> an application.

In this way the location of your database could be easily managed from inside of your application.
You can change the actual directory pointed by `DataDirectory` using this command (before any data access code is executed)

```
string commonFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
string myAppFolder = Path.Combine(commonFolder, "MyAppDataFolder");
// This willl do nothing if the folder already exists
Directory.CreateDirectory(myAppFolder);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", myAppFolder);
```

This will resolve (on Win7) to `C:\programdata\myappdatafolder\database1.mdf`

Comment: before `\Database1.mdf` do I add any other path? or just like you posted it?

Comment: Usually the correct folder is a subfolder of the CommonApplicationFolder. Added an example

Comment: I get a lot of errors on the code about commonFolder, like `invalid token '(' `

Comment: Yes sorry, copy, paste, removed the spurious `)`

Comment: Οn the AppDomain.CurrentDomain i get this error

`Error 1 Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration E:\Σχολή\Τεχνολογία Λογισμικού\Εργασία\Scholarships\Scholarships\Form3.cs 17 40 Scholarships
`

Comment: Can't imagine what is wrong on your side, checks these links if you find something useful... [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.AppDomain.aspx), [CurrentDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx), [SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Make the path to your db file configurable in [appsettings in your app.config](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/291570/How-to-access-a-app-configs-appsettings-key-value).